# Some SVG are not taking transition on :hover

Tags: php, css, svg, hover, css-transitions

My footer includes several SVG codes, some of them are from FontAwesome and some of them were converted to SVG path in AI.

The issue I'm facing is that the SVG codes converted in AI are not taking any transition property on hover, besides those from FA do. The color change on hovering works, it's just the transition that does not. I've tried it also with keyframes, but it worked only on the FA ones.

Markup is in PHP.

```css
#footer-brands:hover {
  transition: var(--transition);
  fill: var(--primary-color);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/145901020@N03/">
  <svg id="footer-brands" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <path d="M151 58a42 42 0 1 0 .1 0z" />
  <path d="M49 58a42 42 0 1 0 .1 0z" />
  </svg>
</a>
<a href="https://github.com">
  <svg id="footer-brands" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 496 512">
  <path d="M165.9 397.4c0 2-2.3 3.6-5.2 3.6-3.3.3-5.6-1.3-5.6-3.6 0-2 2.3-3.6 5.2-3.6 3-.3 5.6 1.3 5.6 3.6zm-31.1-4.5c-.7 2 1.3 4.3 4.3 4.9 2.6 1 5.6 0 6.2-2s-1.3-4.3-4.3-5.2c-2.6-.7-5.5.3-6.2 2.3zm44.2-1.7c-2.9.7-4.9 2.6-4.6 4.9.3 2 2.9 3.3 5.9 2.6 2.9-.7 4.9-2.6 4.6-4.6-.3-1.9-3-3.2-5.9-2.9zM244.8 8C106.1 8 0 113.3 0 252c0 110.9 69.8 205.8 169.5 239.2 12.8 2.3 17.3-5.6 17.3-12.1 0-6.2-.3-40.4-.3-61.4 0 0-70 15-84.7-29.8 0 0-11.4-29.1-27.8-36.6 0 0-22.9-15.7 1.6-15.4 0 0 24.9 2 38.6 25.8 21.9 38.6 58.6 27.5 72.9 20.9 2.3-16 8.8-27.1 16-33.7-55.9-6.2-112.3-14.3-112.3-110.5 0-27.5 7.6-41.3 23.6-58.9-2.6-6.5-11.1-33.3 2.6-67.9 20.9-6.5 69 27 69 27 20-5.6 41.5-8.5 62.8-8.5s42.8 2.9 62.8 8.5c0 0 48.1-33.6 69-27 13.7 34.7 5.2 61.4 2.6 67.9 16 17.7 25.8 31.5 25.8 58.9 0 96.5-58.9 104.2-114.8 110.5 9.2 7.9 17 22.9 17 46.4 0 33.7-.3 75.4-.3 83.6 0 6.5 4.6 14.4 17.3 12.1C428.2 457.8 496 362.9 496 252 496 113.3 383.5 8 244.8 8zM97.2 352.9c-1.3 1-1 3.3.7 5.2 1.6 1.6 3.9 2.3 5.2 1 1.3-1 1-3.3-.7-5.2-1.6-1.6-3.9-2.3-5.2-1zm-10.8-8.1c-.7 1.3.3 2.9 2.3 3.9 1.6 1 3.6.7 4.3-.7.7-1.3-.3-2.9-2.3-3.9-2-.6-3.6-.3-4.3.7zm32.4 35.6c-1.6 1.3-1 4.3 1.3 6.2 2.3 2.3 5.2 2.6 6.5 1 1.3-1.3.7-4.3-1.3-6.2-2.2-2.3-5.2-2.6-6.5-1zm-11.4-14.7c-1.6 1-1.6 3.6 0 5.9 1.6 2.3 4.3 3.3 5.6 2.3 1.6-1.3 1.6-3.9 0-6.2-1.4-2.3-4-3.3-5.6-2z" />
  </svg>
</a>
```

,

Comment: #footer-brands:hover>path

Comment: you have multiple elements with the same id value, that's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in the posted code.

Following code works on both Firefox and Chrome on my desktop:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
      #footer-brands {
      transition-property: width;
      transition-duration: 2s;
      transition-timing-function: ease;
      transition-delay: 0s;
      background: red;
      width:100px;
      }
      #footer-brands:hover {
      width: 300px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/145901020@N03/">
      <svg id="footer-brands" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        <path d="M151 58a42 42 0 1 0 .1 0z" />
        <path d="M49 58a42 42 0 1 0 .1 0z" />
      </svg>
    </a>
    <a href="https://github.com">
      <svg id="footer-brands" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 496 512">
        <path d="M165.9 397.4c0 2-2.3 3.6-5.2 3.6-3.3.3-5.6-1.3-5.6-3.6 0-2 2.3-3.6 5.2-3.6 <...>"/>
      </svg>
    </a>      
  </body>
</html>
```

Maybe you did not specify the right transition ?
Or you missed to specify the style of the non-hover svg ?
Or the transition you are specifying has no effect on the second svg, due to its size ?

Comment: The original code started to work since I put it online. I have no idea why but the transition wasn't displaying while running the code on local... Thanks tho!